# Matching Rel Attributes with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

First, please see [this post on Doctype](http://doctype.com/matching-rel-attributes)

I've been trying to get an answer to this, but have not been successful.  The script that the first poster provided works great but, I need this to happen automatically, for all groups of matching Rel's.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
For those of you unable to follow the link above, here is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>match rel</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    $(".photo img").show().css('background','transparent'); //restore visibility
    matchImg($("#relval").val());
  });
});

function matchImg(relVal){
    var sel = ".photo img[rel='" + relVal + "']";
    if ($(sel).length > 0) { //check matching rel
        $(sel + ":gt(0)").hide(); //hide all except first
        $(sel + ":first").css('background','red'); //set background to first
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.photo img {
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="photo">
<img rel="dt" src="http://doctype.com/images/logo-small.png" alt="1" />
<img rel="dt" src="http://doctype.com/images/logo-small.png" alt="2" />
<img rel="dt" src="http://doctype.com/images/logo-small.png" alt="3" />
<img rel="so" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" alt="4" />
<img rel="so" src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" alt="5" />
</div>
<p style="clear: both;">
Enter 'dt' or 'so' <input type="text" value="dt" id="relval" />
<input type="button" value="match" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I'm taking a grid-layout of photos and modifying them. Some photos are related and some are not. The ones that are related will have matching Rel attributes. I would like jquery to recognize a group of related images (with the same rel), hide all of the images except the first and apply a background image to the container of the first photo (not finalized yet but, it will likely be a div or li).

**This script already does this.**

However, I need the script to do this automatically, with all matching rel groups, without me having to enter in the rel attribute.

Comment: Imagine the URL you supplied was dead. Now, how can I help you? Please ASK the actual question.

Comment: The `rel` attribute is only allowed for `a` and `link` elements. You should use classes instead.

Comment: If you can come up with a script that performs the same function with classes, be my guest :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the first thing the script would have to do would be to figure out all the "rel" values.

```
$(function() {
 var allRels = {};
 $('img[rel]').each(function() {
   allRels[$(this).attr('rel')] = true;
 });
```

Then you can go through and hide all but the first (or whatever it is that you want to do):

```
$.each(allRels, function(rel) {
  $('img[rel=' + rel + ']').each(function(i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      // $(this) is the first image with this particular "rel" value
    }
    else {
      // $(this) is another image in the group, but not the first
    }
  });
});
```

});

I haven't tested that but maybe you get the idea.

Comment: Good start but unfortunately, there is going to be hundreds of Rel attributes.  I would not be able to define them all.  Basically, I am using jquery to modify HTML pages, generated by another piece of software.

Comment: Well you're not *defining* them here, you're *finding* them. The code looks at what's there in the page and effectively creates a "set" data structure of all unique values. I've edited the post to fix up the initial block of code that would do that.